# DocuSign Exception handling

Tags: java, docusignapi

I am using DocuSign Java SDK and trying to get access token using JWT flow.
When I call `ApiClient.requestJWTUserToken` I got error:

> "POST https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/token returned a response status of 400 Bad Request"

But when I set debugging true then I got the actual error message:

> {
>       "error": "consent_required"
>       }

How can I get the real error?

Answer (score 0):

You need to get consent first using the specified account.

This is a one time event using this URL:
https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/auth?response_type=code&scope=signature%20impersonation&client_id={ClientID}&redirect_uri={Your URI}

Comment: Thanks for your reply but why I am not able to get this error DocuSign SDK ApiException. ApiException is not returning any status code and proper error. It's only returning a message like 'Error while requesting an access token: POST https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/token returned a response status of 400 Bad Request'

Comment: Sadly, that is another issue and I am unsure. It is possible your call to get the token is not formatted properly.